# How do I install Phoenix OS to dual boot with Windows 7?

Tags: multi-boot, phoenix

I have an older PC (1gb ram and Intel G33/G31 express chipset family graphics), on which I want to play android games like Clash of Clans and PUBG, but emulators are laggy and their performance is not so well. So I decided to install Phoenix OS along with my Windows 7 Ultimate on my hard disk D with 39.9 GB space.

Whenever I try to install it using an `.exe` installer, it shows an unspecific error

> Sorry, an error occurred during installation process.

I am running with 4 hard disks so making a new partition is not a good idea, however I am ready to dedicate drive D to Phoenix OS.

Here are specifications of my PC:

1. 1GB RAM
2. Intel G33/G31 family express chipset family graphics card.
3. Intel dual core processor 2.20ghz
4. 32-bit windows 7 (x86) and with a 64 bit capable CPU
5. PCI-E
6. BIOS enabled

**Note:**
If it is not possible to install Phoenix OS then please tell about some other alternative. I need to install only on hard disk so tell a method too to do that in case any of you give some alternative that installs on USB flash drive. And I currently cannot upgrade my PC.

Ask any other info required, I will add it.
And if I have posted this question on the wrong site, then I apologize.
Kindly tell me where to post it and delete it after informing me.
Also put correct tags to my question, I don't have much knowledge.

Comment: How far did the installer get? Did it resemble their [Installation Guide](http://www.phoenixos.com/help/installation/help-en), or failed immediately? Was it running as an administrator? *[An install program, or any program really, should be written to give more descriptive errors, Phoenix OS isn't instilling confidence here]*

Comment: @Xen2050 it installed same as guides but when the "installation successful reboot now " should come I get the error

Comment: Hmm... if it really did finish installing, then what happens when you reboot? Also, it looks like there is (or at least was) a [Phoenix OS downloader](http://bbs.phoenixstudio.org/en/showthread.php?pid=10827#pid10827) that should "automatically determine to install 32/64 bit according to your device"

Comment: @Xen2050 you did not understand what I said..I meant that when the installation should finish and ask me to reboot my system to Phoenix it instead shows me the error

Comment: So... maybe it got close enough to finish installing, nothing happens on reboot? Maybe the end error is minor. Anyway, their website's help/forums are probably the best place for help, did you search there already, what'd you find?

Comment: i could not find something useful for me at the forums you are telling about